# Ttk notebook too many frames causes glitch

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am creating a simple SQLite database viewer in Tkinter/Ttk. It consists of a ttk notebook with a table in each tab. For smaller tables, it loads fine but for tables with 1000+ rows it glitches.
How it should look:
[image: Working layout]
How it looks on large tables:
[image: Not working]
(The white part at the top overlays other windows which is a bit weird)
 Is there a better way to load the tables such that this does not occur?

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
import random

class dbTable(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def populateTable(self, data):
        for n1, line in enumerate(data):
            if n1 == 0: #Header
                bg = "lightgray"
            else:
                bg = "white"
            for n2, item in enumerate(line):
                f = tk.Frame(self, highlightthickness = 1, highlightbackground = "black", bg = bg)
                f.grid(row = n1, column = n2, sticky = "nesw")
                l = tk.Label(f, bg = bg, text = item)
                l.pack(padx = 3, pady = 3, fill = "both", expand = True)
        if len(data) == 1:
            f = tk.Label(self, text = "No data")
            f.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = len(data[0]))
class DatabaseViewer(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Database viewer")
        self.loadData()
        self.openViewer()
    def loadData(self):
        self.tables = ["example"]
        self.tableHeaders = {"example":("header1","header2","header3","header4")}
        randData = [(n, random.randint(10,20000000), random.randint(10,20000000), random.randint(10,20000000), random.randint(10,20000000)) for n in range(1000)]
        self.tableData = {"example":randData}
    def openViewer(self):
        self.viewerFrm = tk.Frame(self)
        self.viewerFrm.pack()
        self.viewerNotebook = ttk.Notebook(self.viewerFrm)
        self.viewerNotebook.pack()
        for table in self.tables:
            f = tkinter.Frame(self.viewerNotebook)
            self.viewerNotebook.add(f, text = table)
            t = dbTable(f)
            t.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
            t.populateTable([self.tableHeaders[table]] + self.tableData[table])

app = DatabaseViewer()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and be more specific than just saying "it glitches".

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that doesn't rely on your database. I suspect your problem exists whether the data comes from a database or if it comes from a loop.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've changed the code but this doesn't reproduce the problem exactly, although it's similar

Comment: @martineau I have edited the question

Comment: I think this may be a tkinter / tcl bug because I see nothing (important) wrong and have been able to verify that it works for a smaller number of rows. With 1000 rows there's was an APPCRASH  in python.exe d WIndows indicates there was a fault with exception code 80000003 in the `tcl86t.dll` module (version 8.6.2.9).

Comment: @martineau Thanks for looking into this, I guess that means there's not really a fix?

Comment: @Henry: Unfortunately I think that's the case. Even though1000 rows seems a bit excessive, a properly-written module ought to be able to avoid crashing as well as avoid the visual "glitches". You're best bet might be to find some other module that does what you need (short of writing your own). I've heard of some called "tktables", "tkinter tables", or something along those lines.